# Why should the cord connecting the carrier to the hanging pan and passing through the pulley be made parallel to the horizontal box cover?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram, string

Why should the cord connecting the carrier to the hanging pan and passing through the pulley be made parallel to the horizontal box cover when doing the experiment in determining the coefficient of static friction?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it wasn't parallel, the force it would impose on the carrier would have a vertical component, which would have the effect of changing the effective weight of the carrier by pulling it up or down somewhat.